# Creating a vector in R using 1+pi, 1+2pi.....1+19pi, using the pi symbol

Tags: r, vector

I need to create something like

```
b= (1,1+pi, 1+2pi, 1+3pi, 1+4pi,..., 1+19pi)
```

but so far I haven't found the way. I have used seq() and c(), but it only adds up to pi and the number.

I'm new to R. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: `1 + (0:19)*pi`. But I don't think you're going to want to ask on the internet for the very fundamental basics. What you need to do is go through "An Introduction to R" to get a basic handle on things.

Comment: `seq(1, by=pi, length.out = 20)`

Comment: Your expected result is unclear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#Define a vector of costants
a <- rep(1, 20)

#Define a sequence from 0 to 19
c <- c(0:19)

#Create the final vector
b <- a + pi*c
```

Comment: Aside from being a non-`R` way of doing things, you really shouldn't be giving variables the same names as important functions (`c`).

Comment: @ngm I agree on giving a wrong name to the vector. I wasn't thinking about it.

Comment: @DavideBottoli You are right, I misread your `rep(...)` as `1:20`, sorry (... but I am not the only one). BTW: The `rep(...)`is not needed. Use the *recycling rule* `b <- 1 + pi*c` Another shortening: `c <- 0:19`

Comment: @Gregor you should run my code. it's NOT 
`b <- (a + pi)*c`

Comment: @jogo we agree on this. But since this guy seems to be at the beginning of learning, I thought it might have been easier for him to sum two vectors, since he's probably not aware of _recycling rule_

Comment: Thank you guys, I really appreciated all your help. I'm taking a class on R and this is one of my first assignments, but the professor has not explained how to do complex vectors in class.